# no function clause matching in Keyword.get/3

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I’m new to elixir and when I run my api it throws an error. Not sure what is wrong.

**UserController**

```
def index(conn, params, _current_user, _params) do
    page = Accounts.list_all_users(params)

    conn
    |> Scrivener.Headers.paginate(page)
    |> render("index.json", all_users: page.entries)
end
```

**Error**

```
[info] GET /api/manage/all_users
[debug] Processing with Pxf.Web.Admin.UserController.index/2
  Parameters: %{}
  Pipelines: [:api]
[info] Sent 500 in 278ms
[error] #PID<0.1130.0> running Pxf.Web.Endpoint (connection #PID<0.1129.0>, stream id 1) terminated
Server: localhost:8000 (http)
Request: GET /api/manage/all_users
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Keyword.get/3
        (elixir 1.14.2) lib/keyword.ex:388: Keyword.get(:default, :key, nil)
        (guardian 2.3.1) lib/guardian/plug.ex:373: Guardian.Plug.fetch_key/2
        (guardian 2.3.1) lib/guardian/plug.ex:141: Guardian.Plug.current_resource/2
        (pxf 0.1.0) lib/pxf/web/controllers/load_resource.ex:30: Pxf.Plug.LoadResource.call/2
        (pxf 0.1.0) Pxf.Router.api/2
        (pxf 0.1.0) lib/pxf/web/router.ex:1: Pxf.Router.__pipe_through1__/1
        (phoenix 1.6.15) lib/phoenix/router.ex:346: Phoenix.Router.__call__/2
        (pxf 0.1.0) lib/plug/error_handler.ex:80: Pxf.Router."call (overridable 3)"/2
        (pxf 0.1.0) lib/pxf/web/router.ex:1: Pxf.Router.call/2
        (pxf 0.1.0) lib/pxf/web/endpoint.ex:1: Pxf.Web.Endpoint.plug_builder_call/2
        (pxf 0.1.0) lib/pxf/web/endpoint.ex:1: Pxf.Web.Endpoint."call (overridable 3)"/2
        (pxf 0.1.0) lib/pxf/web/endpoint.ex:1: Pxf.Web.Endpoint.call/2
        (phoenix 1.6.15) lib/phoenix/endpoint/cowboy2_handler.ex:54: Phoenix.Endpoint.Cowboy2Handler.init/4
        (cowboy 2.9.0) /../dev/pxf-phoenix-v1.4/deps/cowboy/src/cowboy_handler.erl:37: :cowboy_handler.execute/2
        (cowboy 2.9.0) /../dev/pxf-phoenix-v1.4/deps/cowboy/src/cowboy_stream_h.erl:306: :cowboy_stream_h.execute/3
        (cowboy 2.9.0) /../dev/pxf-phoenix-v1.4/deps/cowboy/src/cowboy_stream_h.erl:295: :cowboy_stream_h.request_process/3
        (stdlib 4.1.1) proc_lib.erl:240: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
```

**Edits**
**api pipeline in router**

```
  pipeline :api do
    plug(:accepts, ["json", :images])
    plug(VerifyHeader, realm: "Bearer")
    plug(LoadResource)
    plug(:log_ip)
  end
```

**load_resource.ex (line 30-42)**

```
case Guardian.Plug.current_resource(conn, key) do
      nil ->
        case Guardian.Plug.claims(conn, key) do
          {:ok, claims} ->
            claims |> load_resource(opts) |> put_current_resource(conn, key)

          {:error, _} ->
               Guardian.Plug.set_current_resource(conn, nil, key)
        end

      _ ->
        conn
    end
```

Also I'm receiving "*Something went wrong*" error when the api is called with 500 Internal Server Error.

Not sure how to debug to find out what is going. Please need some help on this.

thanks

Comment: looking in the stack trace it seems that the error is not in your controller but in your router configuration, more specifically your Guardian setting. Can you post your `:api` pipeline?

Comment: The fundamental error is `Keyword.get(:default, :key, nil)` -- instead of something like `Keyword.get([foo: "bar", key: "val"], :key, nil)`, the first argument is arriving as `:default`, which isn't a keyword list, so the function fails.  We'd need more info (like Evaldo says), but maybe you can do `IO.inspect(page)` or finding anywhere that is setting a value of `:default` instead of a list.

Comment: It seems that the error is in the here lib/pxf/web/controllers/load_resource.ex (line 30). What's here?

Comment: Added pipeline and load_resource.ex line 30 code as well.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code of a custom `LoadResource` you should send a `Keyword` as the second argument (as [Everett](https://stackoverflow.com/users/274030/everett) said). I'd start with changing this

```
case Guardian.Plug.current_resource(conn, key) do
```

to

```
case Guardian.Plug.current_resource(conn, [key: key]) do
```

And then proceed with further errors if there's any.

Not sure what you're trying to achieve as it's hard to guess by the code fragments but there is a `Guardian.Plug.LoadResource` out of the box. Perhaps it will be a better option for you to start instead of a custom `LoadResource` module.